# mysql select from one server insert to another mysql server?

Tags: mysql

I wont to do insert to one mysqll server to and get the data or do the select part 
of the insert into select from anther mysql server 
not just copy entire tables is this possible in my sql 
I know that in MS Sql server you can do a linked server

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excellent, FOSS, cross-platform [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) query tool supports exactly this, for any database you have a JDBC driver for, as documented in [this](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-copy.html#command-copy-query) manual page.